# Xcode 9.2 changed the storyboard when I import the project which was developed in Xcode 9.0.

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, xcode9.2

I have a project which I developed in Xcode 9.0. Now after installing 9.2 I imported the same project and I found so many constraint error in my storyboard. I thought last time I did any mistake in my storyboard. So I discard all the changes and reopen the project. Here I found same issue. The new xcode version changed all the components.

```
    - <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="বিশ্বসেরা রোনালদো " textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="d4F-gk-hQG">
    - <rect key="frame" x="77" y="45" width="282" height="21"/>
    + <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" ambiguous="YES" text="বিশ্বসেরা রোনালদো " textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="d4F-gk-hQG">
    + <rect key="frame" x="84" y="45" width="268" height="21"/>
```

So  here x value of the frame changed 77 to 84. How can I solve that?

Comment: Do you mean there’s absolutely no conflicts or anything in the old version and it complains in the new version all of a sudden?

Comment: Is everything still working and showing the same when running? Cause I noticed that the x and y values sometimes change by simply opening the storyboard but things still work

Comment: @ChrisBorg It is running and working but the error symbol in the storyboard distracting me and also I am confused that it will work on all other device or not.

Comment: @pearl7721 Many people reported the issue. I already mentioned that I discarded all the changes and open the project on both Xcode 9.0 and Xcode 9.2 on two separate mac from my git repository. In 9.0 it did not show any error mark in storyboard but in 9.2 it shows.

Comment: And what happens if you right-click storyboard > source control > discard changes while in Xcode 9.2?

Comment: Anyone found answer to this